# How do I fix the exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' while using the connection string for excel?

Tags: c#, excel, ado.net, oledbconnection

I am trying to connect an excel file to my C# code. However, the code throws an exception: "'ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'"? What could I do to fix it?

```
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection();
    con.ConnectionString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource='D:/.Net devlop/ADO_QuickKart Application_14Nov16_1807/QuikkartDB.xlsx';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES'";
```

Comment: Your path uses `'` and `/`. I suspect both are problematic. https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/

Answer (score 0):

Your path contains  ' , which is causing the issue.

Example:

```
Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue with \ and '.

```
string filePath = "D:\\.Net devlop\\ADO_QuickKart Application_14Nov16_1807\\QuikkartDB.xlsx";

string connectionString = $"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source={filePath};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
```

Or use OleDb.[OleDbConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnectionstringbuilder?view=netframework-4.8)

```
OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder Builder = new OleDb.OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
Builder.DataSource = "test.xlsx";
Builder.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0";
Builder.Add("Extended Properties", "Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1");
Console.WriteLine(Builder.ConnectionString);
```

Comment: Have you installed Microsoft Access Database Engine Redistributable? If not try installing it